# Раскрывающаяся / закрывающаяся таблица iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста реализовать таблицу с кастомными ячейками, которая разворачивается и сворачивается. Код подсмотрел вот здесь http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/ но в реализации не все понятно, чтобы смочь самому переделать таблицу под свои нужды. Вчитывался и мало что понял, как она работает. Кто-нибудь делал похожую таблицу либо может есть другие варианты реализации попроще? Вот схема: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmgwil25qn6o0da/Accordion.jpg

Comment: [Похожий вопрос][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/254843/objective-c-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: Мне несложно скопировать код и вставить нужные мне названия ячеек, но мне нужны кастомные ячейки в такой таблице. Я как понял в IB я такие не сделаю, потому что мне нужно разделение на секции. Получается, что при разворачивании "родительской" ячейки должна выскочить "дочерняя" таблица, с разделенными на секции ячейками с текстовыми полями. Я не знаю как это все вставить в существующие готовые модели таких таблиц. Причем больше всего устраивает меня эта http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/

Comment: @Kid, тогда задавайте более конкретные вопросы. Вообще разбейте задачу на более мелкие и решайте по одной, думается мне что никто за вас код писать не будет...

Answer (score 1):

Может [этот пример](https://code.google.com/p/ashiphone/downloads/detail?name=Collapsible-UITableView.zip&can=2&q=) подойдет